# How do I use premake5 along with MinGW?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, premake

I have a simple main.c file which just prints hello world and then I've got the premake5.lua.

```
workspace "HelloWorld"
   configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

project "HelloWorld"
   kind "ConsoleApp"
   language "C"
   targetdir "bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

    files {"main.c"}

   filter "configurations:Debug"
      defines { "DEBUG" }
      symbols "On"

   filter "configurations:Release"
      defines { "NDEBUG" }
      optimize "On"
```

then I ran premake5 gmake2 and it ran perfectly, but when I tried to run make (or mingw32-make) it gave me this error.

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -MD -MP -DDEBUG -g -o obj/Debug/main.o -MF obj/Debug/main.d -c main.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make[1]: *** [HelloWorld.make:129: obj/Debug/main.o] Error 2
```

to make this more interesting, there are no .d files in the bin folder :(

I was expecting a simple hello world program using premake5 and followed the exact steps as provided in the documentations...

Comment: I remember `mingw32-make` being buggy. The plain `make` from MSYS2 works better.

Comment: Try `make CC=gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

The makefile uses `cc` which is generally an alias on a C-compiler (gcc or clang).

Not familiar with (default) install of MinGW, but if you don't have that alias, you might still specify the compiler to the generated makefile:

```
make CC=gcc
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make sure the location of `gcc.exe` is in a location that is listed in the `PATH` environment variable and run:

```bash
make CC=gcc
```

or even:

```bash
make CC=gcc.exe
```

or specify the full path to `gcc.exe` like this:

```bash
make CC="C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe"
```

When using MSYS2 shell and using backslashes make sure to use single quotes:

```bash
make CC='C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe'
```

or use slashes instead of backslashes.